# Pandas bar plot: one bar coloured in palette and the rest single colour

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to figure out whether it'd be possible to create a bar plot in Pandas where one single bar is palette-coloured, meaning all bars are in a chosen colour and just one displays a palette of them (for instance from red to blue).

So let's say that I have this dataframe

[image]

I want to plot the bars for column *my_col*, each with the colour specified by col *bar_colour*. I know I can give each bar a colour by doing :

```
df['my_col'].plot(kind='bar', 
               stacked=False,
               color=df['bar_colour'])
```

This way I get

[image]

But I'd want the bar for *multi* to have a pattern instead of one colour.
Digging around, I didn't find a way where I could assign a palette to a bar instead of a single colour, is that possible?

Comment: one bar colored in palette.. is it a stacked bar? can you please post sample plot.. ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "palette" here. Are you looking for one bar to have a colour _gradient_? If so, you might try looking here: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/gradient_bar.html

Comment: @SayaliSonawane Please see updated question, I added example.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html this will give you color list supported by matplotlib